nasty geometry problem - not sure how to solve for unknown segment lengths

I know the height of the pentagonal (and pentagrammic) pyramid H, the circumradius of the inner pentagon r$_\text{c}$, and the height of the green triangle(s) h.  Using this information, is there a way of calculating either d or the length of the small red segment relative to any of those known lengths?  The small red segment, d, r$_\text{c}$, and H form corresponding parts of similar triangles but if I don't know either of the first two that doesn't help me.  I'm hoping this can be solved using just geometry and/or trig but if necessary also finding the dihedral angle between the two congruent yellow heights.
Extra info: The two triangles that share the edge E are the blue triangles on this great icosahedron:


Please let us know what you have tried so far.

Your top figure is a bit confusing. Are the three points (apex of the pyramid, and the two apexes of the two green triangles to the right) all collinear? Based on the edit at the end, it seems like you don’t want them to be collinear. Also, is the top green triangle on the right in the base of the pyramid?

@Pranay Yes, they are all collinear, I probably didn't draw them perfectly.

So $r_c$ and $h$ are determined by $E$, and the only independent quantities are $E$ and $H$.

@Pranay H is also determined by E.  If you look at the great icosahedron, notice that the edge of each pentagonal pyramid's lateral face has a length of E$\varphi$.  Drawing in the circumradius of the outer pentagon (also determined by E), one can set up a right triangle and use the Pythagorean Theorem.

(The outer pentagon of the top diagram)

From the figure below, we conclude that
$$
\tan \theta = {r_c \over H},\quad d= h\sin 2\theta,
$$
where $\sin 2\theta = {2\tan\theta \over 1+\tan^2\theta}$.


How do you know that angle 2$\theta$ has twice the measure of angle $\theta$?

@John The triangle with the two $h$ legs is isosceles, and the two equal angles are $\pi/2-\theta$.

Sweet!  Thank you so much! :-)
